# Is it possible to over burden yourself?

Tags: personality

If someone thinks a lot about their future like what are they going to do 1 year down the line or how will the live the rest of their lives and some of these ideas can be really extreme like taking a vow of celibacy in their thoughts. Can they end up over-burdening themselves and if yes then what could be the possible solution to it. Also what are the symptoms of such a man/woman?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Welcome to Psychology.SE! Take a look at https://www.psychologytoday.com/gb/blog/high-octane-women/201311/the-tell-tale-signs-burnout-do-you-have-them.  If nobody beats me to it, I will try to formulate an answer later today

Comment: how can someone get rid of "burnout"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As indicated in my comment, it is possible to "overburden" yourself, and there are different degrees of effects from overburdening depending on severity and timescales.  Any overburden with enough time can lead to burnout ([Carter, 2013](https://www.psychologytoday.com/gb/blog/high-octane-women/201311/the-tell-tale-signs-burnout-do-you-have-them)).  Other names for burnout include ["mental breakdown" or "nervous exhaustion/breakdown"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mental_breakdown).  Another form of burnout, but essentially the same thing is Compassion Fatigue ([Carter, 2014](https://www.psychologytoday.com/gb/blog/high-octane-women/201407/are-you-suffering-compassion-fatigue))

### Definition of Burnout

Burnout is a state of chronic stress that has led to extreme physical and emotional exhaustion, which in turn can lead to cynicism, detachment, and feelings of ineffectiveness and lack of accomplishment.

[Carter (2013)](https://www.psychologytoday.com/gb/blog/high-octane-women/201311/the-tell-tale-signs-burnout-do-you-have-them) has given a good rundown of the problem, but I would suggest subsituting the section header **Signs of Ineffectiveness and Lack of Accomplishment** with **Feelings of Ineffectiveness and Lack of Accomplishment can lead to...**

### Prevention/Remedy for Burnout

This can be a huge subject, but to narrow it down in a nutshell, as burnout is caused by chronic stress, the only way to prevent it or remedy it is to do whatever relieves stress for you and incorporate it into your day, **every day**.  Burning the candle at both ends along with the midnight oil every day is going to lead to burnout.

### References

Carter, S. B. (2013). The Tell Tale Signs of Burnout ... Do You Have Them? *PsychologyToday* [Online]
Retrieved from: https://www.psychologytoday.com/gb/blog/high-octane-women/201311/the-tell-tale-signs-burnout-do-you-have-them

Carter, S. B. (2014). Are You Suffering from Compassion Fatigue?:
What to do when showing compassion feels like a burden *PsychologyToday* [Online]
Retrieved from https://www.psychologytoday.com/gb/blog/high-octane-women/201407/are-you-suffering-compassion-fatigue